# How to precisely cap current

Tags: current, current-limiting

I'm building a device that drives a motor shaft with the possibility of injury or discomfort if the motor receives too much current. The motor will be driven at 48V with max current around 5.2A. It seems like most fuses have a broad range in which they trip or a somewhat lengthy response time, which I think makes them a poor choice for this project.

I'm not looking to clamp the current, just to cap it at a value deemed unsafe. Is there any way to do this without substantial voltage drop? Is there any such circuit that is reliable enough to not allow the current through above a certain value?

The circuit would not act as the sole safety stop, but it would be an important element. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will you handle startup inrush? And do you want to cap? Or cut out when an overcurrent is detected i.e. to let someone not continue to be injured by your motor?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to clamp or cap current (same thing I believe) is to power the motor through an electronic speed controller (ESC). With a DC motor, limiting the current is pretty much the same as limiting torque. Once the current limit is reached, the limiting will reduce the voltage to whatever value is required to hold the current at the set level. It that means reducing the voltage to nearly zero and stopping the motor, that is what must happen.

An alternative to a fuse would be an overcorrect trip that would shut off the motor in the event of excess current. A high quality ESC would have that as an alternative built-in. It could also be accomplished electronically without an ESC.

Both options could be fast accurate and reliable. Neither would address every safety concern. Some situations would demand human access restrictions.

AC motors could have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really good options for limiting current in the current and voltage spec you have.

One could limit the current with a DC motor through the supply and get a 48V 5A supply, but read up on the supply you purchase and how it handles overcurrent (or under voltage conditions)

Another option outside of a fuse is a Positive Temperature Coefficient thermistor (PTC).

[image]

Source: https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/protection/current/ptc-limiter/technote/apn-ptc-thermistor.html